# Task management tools with keyboard navigation that run in a terminal

Tags: top, process-management

I recently learned that I can use  `top` with my keyboard to kill processes (<kbd>k</kbd>), show processes for a specific user only (<kbd>u</kbd>), etc. But I was wondering if there is a way of selecting processes from the menu without having to manually type their `PID`  (e.g. using <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd> to navigate the list would be ideal)

If `top` does not let me do this, are there any tools that can help with this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) fits the bill. It is a nicer `top`.

> Comparison between htop and top
>
> - In 'htop' you can scroll the list vertically and horizontally to see all processes and complete command lines.
> - In 'top' you are subject to a delay for each unassigned key you press (especially annoying when multi-key escape sequences are triggered by accident).
> - 'htop' starts faster ('top' seems to collect data for a while before displaying anything).
> - In 'htop' you don't need to type the process number to kill a process, in 'top' you do.
> - In 'htop' you don't need to type the process number or the priority value to renice a process, in 'top' you do.
> - 'htop' supports mouse operation, 'top' doesn't
> - 'top' is older, hence, more used and tested.

[image]